# Oracle Identity Analytics (OIA) - How does it work and how do companies use it?

Tags: oracle

I am looking to learn a little more about Oracle Identity Analytics (OIA) and how it works in conjunction with other Oracle Identity Management (OIM) products. For example, what is it's role in Identity/Access Management and how do companies typically utilize it?

Answer (score 1):

You can think of OIA as of an accounts and entitlements warehouse where you'd go to figure out who has access to what, when OIM is more oriented to providing automation in managing (granting and revoking access).

Where I work we utilize it mainly for Identity Audit. It covers prevention and reaction to Segregation of Duties violations. ( For example developers shouldn't have direct, high-privileged access to production environment - that would be a violation ). It's done by designing and executing Identity Audit Policies and Rules against set of employees.

Unfortunately the tool has a lot of deficiencies, so one needs to test it thoroughly before making final decision. Some of them you will be able to solve by writing some small scripts, but some of them are fully on Oracle (scaling, performance, WebUI) so you might want to wait to find out more details about OIG (Oracle Identity Governance suite) that they've announced in Oct'12 ( http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/press/1859216 )

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Identity Analytics (OIA) augments the provisioning, re-certification and privileged access components of OIM by allowing you to run Audit Policies and Role Management.

OIM allows you to define roles to automate and simplify provisioning, but it does not have the role mining capability to suggest roles based on Who has access What already.  Therefore in OIM you have to manually define the roles for users.  OIA can partially automate the process by looking at the data bottom up to find commonality.  Oracle suggest a hybrid approach, a combination of the two.

The audit polices are aimed at Separation of Duties (or toxic combinations) which allow you to prevent access being granted where there is a conflict of interest.  A typical example would be the permissions to raise a payment request and permissions to approve a payment request in some software.  This is particularly important in highly regulated environments such as banking and the health sector.

In OIM for Privileged Access you would not normally use a SoD constraint for a user to have both a non-privileged and a privileged account.  In fact you would want a user to by default use the Standard account and then Step-Up through a break glass process to get their password and use a Privileged Access manager to maintain the audit trail.  I am more familiar with CyberArk than the Oracle product included as part of OIM.

Under Oracle Identity Governance 11g PS 2 the licence agreement should give you all the products in the suite. Over time Oracle are further integrating the two products.